# In pytorch, the meaning of y.backward([0.1, 1.0, 0.0001])

Tags: pytorch

In pytorch
what is the meaning of `y.backward([0.1, 1.0, 0.0001])`?

I understand that `y.backward()` means doing backpropagation.
But what is the meaning of `[0.1, 1.0, 0.0001]` in `y.backward([0.1, 1.0, 0.0001])`?

Answer (score 2):

The expression `y.backward([0.1, 1.0, 0.0001])` is actually wrong. It should be `y.backward(torch.Tensor([0.1, 1.0, 0.0001]))`, where `torch.Tensor([0.1, 1.0, 0.0001])` are the Variables of which the derivative will be computed.

---

**Example**:

```python
x = Variable(torch.ones(2, 2), requires_grad=True)
y = (x + 2).mean()
y.backward(torch.Tensor([1.0]))
print(x.grad)
```

Here, `y = (x + 2)/4` and so, `dy/dx_i = 0.25` since `x_i = 1.0`. Also note, `y.backward(torch.Tensor([1.0]))` and `y.backward()` are equivalent.

If you do:

```python
y.backward(torch.Tensor([0.1]))
print(x.grad)
```

it prints:

```python
Variable containing:
1.00000e-02 *
  2.5000  2.5000
  2.5000  2.5000
[torch.FloatTensor of size 2x2]
```

It is simply `0.1 * 0.25 = 0.025`. So, now if you compute:

```python
y.backward(torch.Tensor([0.1, 0.01]))
print(x.grad)
```

Then it prints:

```python
Variable containing:
1.00000e-02 *
  2.5000  0.2500
  2.5000  0.2500
[torch.FloatTensor of size 2x2]
```

Where, `dy/dx_11 = dy/d_x21 = 0.025` and `dy/dx_12 = dy/d_x22 = 0.0025`.

See the function prototype of [**backward()**](http://pytorch.org/docs/0.3.1/autograd.html?highlight=backward#torch.autograd.backward). You may consider looking into this [**example**](http://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/autograd_tutorial.html#gradients).

Answer (score 0):

First, it's not `y.backward([0.1, 1.0, 0.0001]` since in pyTorch, any arguments should be `Tensor`. So the right one should be `y.backward(torch.tensor([0.1, 1.0, 0.0001], dtype=torch.float))`.
Use the link here to check the documents [autograd](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/autograd_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-beginner-blitz-autograd-tutorial-py)

Secondly, this `torch.tensor([0.1, 1.0, 0.0001], dtype=torch.float)` create a 1-d tensor with 3 elements in it. The code `y.backward(torch.tensor([0.1, 1.0, 0.0001])` is actually computing a vector product with the `y`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the autograd when output is a vector. We cannot get gradient of a vector, we need convert this vector into a scaler. The gradient argument is the weight to convert this vector into a scaler.

For example, input: x = [x1,x2,x3] and the operation: y = 2*x = [2*x1,2*x2,2*x3]

Then, we cannot obtain dy/dx. If we have y.backward(torch.tensor([0.1,1,0.001])), it means we have another variable: **output=torch.sum(y*[0.1,1,0.001])=0.2*x1+2*x2+0.002*x3.**

Then, we can get d(out)/dx and d(out)/dx will be stored in x.grad. In our example, x.grad = [d(out)/dx1, d(out)/dx2, d(out)/dx3] = [0.2, 2, 0.002].